Change bottom system softkey navigation ActionBar for Android phones with hardware keys
I haven't found any resources for a non-system app to write to this menu.
 
Many flip phones with differing UIs share this exact same bottom navigation bar, but I can't find its API. External apps, such as the Spotify app, don't automatically populate it. I'd like to develop an app that can hook its own functions into this menu.

Searching for this within documentation is very difficult, as most documentation is for touch devices that no longer interact with hardware keys or bottom navigation menus.
This specific device (Kyocera Dura) runs Android 10.

You can consider using Material Design.

@BobSmith If I can't figure out how to interact with the system menu, this is what I'll do. In the screenshot of Spotify, you can see that the app itself has a nice 3-button navbar, but below it is the blank system navbar. If possible I'd like to be able to interact with that system bar rather than writing my own.

I think the blank system navbar is of back, home and recent apps option buttons. But as your phone seems to be not support those options it's showing as blank.

That's not an Android system UI compoenent.  It's something that OEM wrote themselves.  If interacting with it is possible, you'd need to find their documentation.

@GabeSechan It is unique to flip phones, but it's not unique among manufacturers, which leads me to believe that there's an open source implementation. I don't think it's in the official Android or AOSP docs, but I'm hoping it exists somewhere. If it doesn't, is there a way to reverse engineer system components using adb or something?

There may be, or they may all have their own implementations, meant to work with their own UI customizations.  My experience with OEMs says the second is more likely.  But your best bet is still to look up the model you know and see if you can find their documentation.

Hm, ok. They don't have official documentation, and I even emailed them to ask about it, but for now I'll use other resources. I found source code that defines a KCfpSoftkey wrapper (after importing jp.kyocera.kcfp.***) Is it possible to write code that interacts with the menu without importing the manufacturer library? If my goal is to write flip phone apps for everybody should I abandon looking for a common API and just write my own softkey menu?
